# Reloading page with the html received as a result of AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using AJAX calls and getting JSON as response then it is used to perform various operations. However there are times when I will get HTML response instead of AJAX(a full HTML page), in such cases I want to reload the page with the HTML content (as if a redirection happened). I am able to find out whether a response is HTML or JSON, however I am unable to find a way in which I can reload the page with HTML content received as part of response so that user only sees the HTML content received as part of AJAX response.

Here is the code:

```
function redirectIfHTML(xhr,data){
        var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "";
        if (ct.indexOf('html') > -1) {
            //  Need to reload the data on current window
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nuke and rewrite the entire content of the page using `document.write()`:

```
document.write("<html><body><p>Hello world!</p></body></html>");
```

If you want to keep the `<head>` (and therefore your CSS and so forth) a cleaner solution is to replace the content of the body:

```
$('body').html("<p>Hello world!</p>");
```

Comment: There is an on page load event in the HTML received which will redirect the user to some other page. This will just replace the contents and would not trigger the on page load event.

Comment: See: [MDN document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) for a working example.  "calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open which will clear the document."

Answer (score 0):

I would never want to do something like this, but you can use some data-url to solve:

A data-URI with MIME-type text/html + the html you just received:

```
var myurl = 'data:text/html,' + <HTML HERE>
```

Then you do:

```
document.location.href = myurl
```

(i didn't really try it)

Comment: maybe this will even trigger the events?